# html drop down list fetch the data in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to fetch data from a dropdown list like I have chosen agent id and agent name that fetch the data in a database I will store agent id in a database table
my error in agent id is not stored in a database

```
<?php
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT agent_name From agent order by agent_id");
$row = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
  echo "<option value='" . $row['agent_id'] . "'>" . $row['agent_name'] . "</option>";

    }
    ?>
    </select>



    <label>Agent</label>
     <select class="form-control" name="agent_name" id="agent_name">
```

Comment: $row['agent_id'] will get error. Change query to SELECT agent_id,agent_name From agent order by agent_id

Answer (score -4, accepted):

html tags are not properly used in above question..i have changed it

```
  <?php
  $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT agent_name,agent_id From agent order by           agent_id");
  $num = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
  ?>
  <label>Agent</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="agent_name" id="agent_name">
  <?php
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
   echo "<option  value='".$row['agent_id']."'>".$row['agent_name'] . "</option>";
   }
   ?>
   </select>
```

Comment: as per comments above - this also does not select `agent_id`

Comment: this is amazing that you didn't even manage to answer it properly

Comment: I agree - seems fishy to me - it's virtually the same as the original code

Comment: @Adnanhaider of course not. Some noobs simply accept anything, thinking they are bound to

Comment: html tags are not properly used in above question..i have changed it